# Rails 4: How to include associated objects conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Product.first.reviews.includes(:comments).where('comments.reply_to_id=?', nil)
```

So basically I want to load the product reviews along with any associated comments.

*Comments belong to the review, not on the product*.

Here is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'comments.reply_to_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `reviews`.* FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviews`.`product_id` = 8 AND (comments.reply_to_id=NULL)
```

From `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "reply_to_id",      limit: 4
  end
```

Comment: In which model `reply_to_id` column belongs to ?

Comment: Can you please double check. The DB is saying no such column in the `comments` table.

Comment: Check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I missed a very obvious thing. Sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [**API**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference

You need to include `.references` at the end of the query when you are using `includes` with ***conditions***

```
Product.first.reviews.includes(:comments).where('comments.reply_to_id=?', nil).references(:comments)
```

Answer (score 2):

@pavan is right. But you can use `Hash` syntax, which finds it out automatically.

```
Product
 .first
 .reviews
 .includes(:comments)
 .where(comments: { reply_to_id: nil })
```

Comment: More elegant. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @Pavan I just forgot the fact, and reading `.includes` as `joins`. :p